# .htaccess redirects for posts in new directory and new domain

Tags: htaccess

Trying to do *global* 301 redirects in .htaccess file from:

domain.com/old/name-of-post

to

newdomain.com/new/name-of-post

The last segment of the url is dynamic based off the post title "name-of-post" and remains the same on both sites but the "old/new" and "domain.com/newdomain.com" have changed.  My goal is to not have to go through and add hundreds of individual redirects.

Any insight on this anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You could use mod_rewrite with some regex like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/old/(.*)/?$ http://newdomain.com/new/$1 [R=302,L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

This would go in the .htaccess file in the olddomain.com document root.

I'd suggest leaving it as a 302 until you are sure it's having the desired effect, as most browsers will cache 301's and then not look at your .htaccess anymore just follow the cached routes - which can be tricky to clear (you definitely don't want to be explaining how to clear them to end users!).

Also, this isn't really a WP question.